# Флаги. Переменные, биты или поля бит?

Tags: c, c++, производительность

С точки зрения быстродействия, на архитектуре x86 какой вариант создания набора флагов наиболее оптимален - структура + поля бит, биты простой переменной, отдельные переменные в 1 байт для каждого флага. Насколько чувствительна разница?

Comment: Напишите тест. Все сильно зависит от задачи. У меня в неоторых задачах выигрывали массивы по байту на бит, а  в некоторых - ручной доступ до битов.

Comment: Результат будет ещё сильно зависеть от компилятора и выбранного уровня оптимизации

Comment: Если интерес не умозрительный, то что же это за **практическая** задача, в которой **можно измерить** влияние реализации флагов на время выполнния ?

Что-нибудь embedded ?

Comment: Кажется даже существуют процессоры с x86 архитектурой под embedded, но используются крайне редко. Целевая машина слабенькая, интерес где то посередине между умозрительным и практическим.

Comment: Виндовый ВOOLEAN размером 1б определенно быстрее из перечисленных, можно сразу сказать, без тестов.

Comment: IMHO "внутренняя жизнь ОС" не позволит провести достоверные измерения влияния реализации флагов на время выполнения реальной программы.

    Если долго вглядываться в бездну, бездна начинает вглядываться в тебя. Фридрих Ницше.

Comment: Возможно стоило задать вопрос немного другим образом:
Операции установки, удаления и проверки флага будут выполняться быстрее на архитектуре x86-32 при каком из вышеуказанных вариантов исполнения флагов (или при любом другом исполнений). Именно с точки зрения архитектуры.

Comment: Хорошая переформулировка вопроса. Начиная с Pentium для практического исполненя программы *однозначно* ответить трудно. Большое влияние оказывает кэш, многопроцессорность, многозадачность и другие факторы. 

Если серьезно, то это **действительно сложный** вопрос.

В практике *программирования* пишите так, как будет Вам удобнее писать, а другим *программистам* читать. Ну, использовать по слову памяти на флаг вряд ли разумно (читатели не оценят).

Comment: Мне удобно в любом варианте. При грамотном оформлении и некотором опыте что ли, или привычке, читать тоже удобно в любом варианте. Я думаю человек, который хорошо разбирается в архитектуре х86 сможет более точно ответить, мои познания в этой области довольно прозрачны, мне всегда казалось, что операции с битами одни из самых дешевых, по количеству затраченных тактов. Сейчас я более близко столкнулся с этим вопросом. И мне стало интересно действительно ли это так, и если дешевле, то на какие порядки.

Comment: Все регистровые операции (целочисленные, м.б. исключая умножение и деление) в современных CPU выполняются за один такт.  При доступе к операндам в памяти возможны задержки (до сотен тактов процессора). Исполнение одной команды разбивается на несколько последовательных этапов (конвейер). В каждом такте одновременно на разных стадиях конвейера исполняется несколько команд.

Чтобы исполнительные устройства процессора не простаивали производится динамическое изменение порядка выполнения команд (и другие действия, повышающие производительность).

Поэтому оценка времени исполнения вопрос сложный.

Comment: @avp, таки таблицы тайминга инструкций никуда не делись, выиграет та структура данных, у на чтение\запись элементов которой тратится меньше. Из перечисленных - массив учаров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лимит комментариев исчерпан. Поэтому приходится отвечать [@karmadro4](/users/6679/karmadro4) в ответе.

Вы правы, таблицы тайминга не пропали. Только пользуясь ими очень сложно посчитать время выполнения фрагмента программы. Задержки по данным, связанные с заполнением кэшей и TLB неочевидны (они зависят от исполнения других потоков и прерываний в системе).

Также, не зная конкретных значений обрабатывемых данных, невозможно предсказать предвыборку команд, операндов и внеочередное выполнение команд.

Обмен данными между кэшем и ОЗУ происходит строками кэша (обычно 32 байта), а между кэшем и буферами АЛУ словами (32 или 64 разряда) поэтому "учары" ничего не меняют, по сравнению с "улонгами".

Я еще раз повторяю, данная тема очень интересная, но не очевидная.

Comment: @avp, я немного углублюсь в философию науки и предложу абстрагироваться от влияния неизвестных случайных процессов на изучаемый феномен... Кстати, к ОЗУ выгоднее бы обращаться по адресу, выравненному на границе машинного слова. Думаю, что на 32-битном процессоре, использующем строки размером 32 байта для обмена с кэшем второго уровня, 8 флагов будет выгодно раздуть до `unsigned long[8]`